# How to compile OpenCV native using jni calls in Android

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new using Android and JNI calls. I have done a simple algorithm made in C++ using OpenCV to detect faces. 
Now to do the same for Android, I want to call the algorithm made in C++ from Java.
The problem is when I try to compile OpenCV native, Gradle build says: "Error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory"
I'm not able to compile headers from native OpenCV.

That's my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)


# OpenCV
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include <path_to_android_OpenCV>/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := opencvjni
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I<path_to_android_OpenCV>/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include -Wall -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := openCVJNI.c detect_face.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += <path_to_project>/app/src/main/jni
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += <path_to_android_OpenCV>/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := <path_to_android_OpenCV>/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/libs/armeabi-v7a/*.a

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

That's is my Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

And that's my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }
    ndk {
        moduleName "openCVJNI"
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11") // Add provisions to allow C++11 functionality
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        stl = "gnustl_shared"
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        commandLine '<_path_to_NDK>/ndk-bundle/build/ndk-build', '-C', file('app/src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

If anyone can help me, it's be grateful. I'm terrified with that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html

In the link below, it is mentioned under LOCAL_C_INCLUDES section:

> Define this variable before setting any corresponding inclusion flags
>   via LOCAL_CFLAGS or LOCAL_CPPFLAGS.

Comment: Not working. Anyone got including opencv native files in android? The worst task I' ever try to do.

Comment: you have opencv native libs already built (*.a). remove the "include OpenCV.mk" part and try again.

Comment: I'm using gradle experimental 0.7.2, but I'm not able to include opencv headers in jni. Do you have any example or tutorial which explains how to do that? Thanks for your patience and attention.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ndk-build, I use custom build system with cmake, I can provide more info on opencv+cmake